# No manifest file Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

They've send me a java code (written with Eclipse) that came in a zip. When decompressed, I had the following files:

```
- .settings
  - org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
- bin
  - anon
     - Discovery.class
     - Main$1.class
     - Main.class
     - Server.class
- src
 - anon
     - Discovery.java
     - Main.java
     - Server.java
- .classpath
- .project
- jssc.jar
```

When I try to execute the jssc.jar from the command line, I get a message saying no main manifest attribute.
I have decompressed the jar file to see the manifest and what it contained:

- jssc: with lots of "class" files inside
- libs: with folders containing files for each OS
- META-INF: with a file manifest

So, it seems that there is a manifest. However, when I open it appears:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
    Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
    X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

What should I do? How do I add the jar file to buildpath?

Comment: I guess you need to execute the main class with jssc inside the classpath, but for that there is plenty of tutorials available. You can also ask "they".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried to execute it with the command: `java -jar jssc.jar` and it failed try to use the following command

```
java -cp jssc.jar anon.Main
```

The above will tell JVM to load jssc.jar in its classpath and then execute the main method in Main class.

Update: if the java program needs more classes than the classes exist in jssc.jar add them in the -cp option with ';' seperator character.

For example:

```
java -cp jssc.jar;bin/anon/;libs/a.jar;libs/;.... anon.Main
```

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I get an error:
```
Error: Main class not found or loaded anon.Main
```

Comment: I assume jssc.jar is just a dependency. So what you actually need is `java -cp jssc.jar;bin/ anon.Main`. It is probably not jssc.jar which contains your anon classes. Can't you ask whoever gave the project to you???

Comment: Exactly @kutschkem, you need to insert the bin/anon package into the classpath so JVM is aware of the Discovery, Server and Main class. Also check that the Main class contains a `public static void main (String[] args)` method.

Comment: @kutschkem Doing what you told me, lead me to:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.nio.file.Files.provider(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)
        at anon.Main.log(Main.java:240)
        at anon.Main.main(Main.java:69)

Comment: @jtrose7 Great! That means it's doing something, and you can start debugging. I advise you again to just talk to the person who gave you the code.

Comment: @kutschkem & Ioannis Barakos Thank you both of you. I will try to contact the person who gave me the code.

Comment: Probably the main method requires an input (one or more input parameters) that you can insert by adding them after the `anon.Main` declaration, e.g. `java -cp jssc.jar;bin/anon/ anon.Main filename1.txt  If you share the main method code we might help more. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should make some modifications on the provided java files, while using the provided .jar file as reference.

So you probably should import the project into eclipse as first step.
To do that:

- Select "File" > "Import..."
- Choose "General" > "Existing Projects into Workspace"
  [image: Import dialog]
- Click "Next >"
- Select "Select archive file:"
  [image: Import existing project]
- Use the "Browse" button to find the archive they gave you.
- Select the project that eclipse will find
- Click the "Finish" button

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to acknowledge that the suggestion by @ioannis-barakos solved the issue for me. I am adding this answer only because my situation is a bit more complicated and will not easily fit in comments to the accepted answer, especially since I intend to be pretty explicit with my explanation.

I came across this question because I was trying to figure out the correct command to run a jar generated by Eclipse/Maven "install" command. The program is modular and makes use of JavaFX as the GUI. The Maven command "clean javafx;run" is successful.

"Why do you want the command to run a jar?" you ask. I wish to share the program with some friends and associates, for feedback. I can use JLINK ("clean javafx:jlink"), but the image created will only work on the Windows OS, not Mac or Linux. A jar file, with the proper command line, should run on Mac. (At least they used to, pretty easily, before jigsaw and the javafx split off.)

So, the successful command line for Windows that I have is as follows:

```
java -cp myProject-0.0.1.jar --module-path "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.graphics,javafx.controls my.package.path.LaunchMyProject
```

As  @ioannis-barakos explains, the **-cp** parameter gives us the class path, and if there were to be additional elements, they would be ";" separated.

As I use JavaFx for the GUI, the path to the JavaFX modules must be included. This is done via the **--module-path** parameter. Additional locations for modules would be ";" separated. The location here can be absolutely spelled out, but I am making use of an environment variable PATH_TO_FX. This points to the */lib* folder within the JavaFX SDK, holding the javafx .jar files. For this, I am following the documentation provide by *Gluon* for [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) Last note, the environment variable is in quotes because I put my JavaFX folders in the same folder as other java jdks, in `c:/program files/java`, and the " " in `program files` is otherwise interpreted as a delimiter.

The list of modules that I added with the **--add-modules** parameter are the ones found in the *module-info.java* file in the *requires* lines. I also have a requires line for *java.desktop* in my module-info, but the local Java (assuming it's a modular version) should already have that covered.

Lastly, the exact syntax of the class holding the main can be found be converting the .jar to a .zip and inspecting the file folders. Note that there are no "/" or "\" in the address, just "." delimiters.